# What command can I use to append data using ftp in SFML?

Tags: c++, ftp, append, sfml

I'm using SFML to upload files on ftp server, but I now wish to just upload some data in every 10min to only one file in the server, i found the function:

```
    Response sf::Ftp::sendCommand(const std::string &command, const std::string& parameter="")
```

but i'm not really good at FTP commands at all, i didn't understood the RFC which has been pointed in [Use of FTP "append" command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536592/use-of-ftp-append-command), does someone know the string command to use for ftp append command?

Comment: According to this: http://www.nsftools.com/tips/RawFTP.htm#APPE I would imagine "APPE" is the command and the remote `filename` is the parameter

Comment: ok i'm going to try this :)